# Xamarin Android совет новичку

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mobile

Вопросов несколько:

- Как можно реализовать взаимодействие с сервером, Веб сокет, могу ли я каким то образом в новом потоке смотреть запрос с сервера?
- Никак не могу понять, xamarin native , xamarin form?
- И есть ли готовое решение по перетаскиванию маркера на гугл мапе с circle options ? Или нужно всегда перерисовывать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Для работы с веб сокетами на xamarin есть готовое решение https://websocket4net.codeplex.com/
2. Также есть готовые решения для работы с Rest итд.
3. Никак не могу понять, xamarin native , xamarin form? Что именно не можете понять?